# ctime_s started replacing leading '0' with space after a compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio, datetime, formatting, ctime

I have a program that when run, generates a log file. The log file is of the format `ProgramName_yymmdd_hhmmss.log`, where those represent year, month, day etc.

It was working fine but then a few weeks ago I changed some of the project property settings and recompiled, and have now noticed that instead of producing it as `ProgramName_171107_124235.log` it produces `ProgramName_1711 7_124235.log`. The difference being the space instead of the 0, which causes the whole thing to crash after a few runs.

```
 // Generate execution date and time string
    time_t ltime;
    char tmpstr[MAXBUF];
    time(&ltime);
    ctime_s(tmpstr, MAXBUF, &ltime);
    // Strip any newline from the end of the string
    if(tmpstr[strlen(tmpstr) - 1] == '\n')
        tmpstr[strlen(tmpstr) - 1] = '\0';

    theApp.ExecutionDate = std::string(tmpstr);
```

There was no changes to the source code, just some switches with linked DLL's. Is there a reason the ctime_s would behave differently under different properties?

Comment: Looks like it is locale dependent.

Comment: That's *very* weird.  `ctime_s` is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ey61ayt.aspx) as returning a string of the form "Wed Jan 02 02:03:55 1980\n\0"  I think you have a local implementation which is locale sensitive.

Comment: What _exactly_  do you get in `tmpstr`?

Comment: I think we need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MartinBonner on my implementation (VS2017) I'm getting this `Tue Nov  7 16:53:57 2017`, (without the trailing `\n`). So I suppose it's heavily locale (or even implementation?) dependent.

Comment: I suggest looking into `strftime(tmpstr, "%y%m%d_%h%M%s", ...`, and can I encourage you to use four digit years with `%Y`?

Comment: @MichaelWalz - that's very odd.  ctime_s only has one implementation - MS and I linked to the MS documentation.  It *is* standardized, but implementation is optional, and as far as I know only MS implement the `_s` stuff (I wish they hadn't gold-plated it, but just stuck to a bit of simple bounds checking.)

Comment: Yes, `strftime` is definitely the best option, that way _you_ are in charge.

Comment: Oh, it is explicitly documented as *not* locale dependant.

Comment: I can confirm `tmpstr`'s value is  `"Tue Nov  7 16:01:09 2017"`

Comment: @MartinBonner OK, but the output I get is definitely contrary to the MS documentation. Well, it's not the first time MS documentation is wrong.

Comment: @PeterKentish is that before or after you replace the `\n`?  It looks like something is parsing the date in `ExecutionDate`, and that something is locale sensitive.

Comment: So apparently the MS implementation doesn't show the leading zeros of the day contrary of what is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ey61ayt.aspx).

Comment: The documentation is right in that the date is still fixed width, it just changed from using a 0 to maintain the width to using a space. I dont understand why this started happening after the recompile, and why it didnt happen before, as the function will not have changed...

Answer (score 0):

The end result here was that `ctime_s` does not perform the function it is expected to perform, in that it pads with spaces and not zeros and so I have decided to switch to `strftime` where I have control over the format.